# Are the children of Han and Leia also royalty?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Princess Leia is a princess, apparently. Even though her planet was destroyed she is still referred to as such. Do her children also inherit the title of prince and princess?

One thing to consider is that she is the adopted daughter of actual royalty. Another thing is consider she is the daughter of an elected queen of Naboo.

Finally we might consider she comes from a broken home (figuratively and later literally) and associates with dissidents and scoundrels on a regular basis.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Note that this information is drawn from a variety of EU works and may include spoilers for certain stories**

Interestingly, royalty is connected to both sides of the Solo-Skywalker union.

Han Solo is possibly descended from [Berethron e Solo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Berethron_e_Solo), a king of Corellia who introduced democracy to the system. Han, through C-3P0 used this to claim that he should marry Leia Organa before a member of the Hapan Royal House could make a claim. At the end of *[The Courtship of Princess Leia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Courtship_of_Princess_Leia)*, C-3P0 finds that the [link](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Korol_Solo) between Han and Berethron may be a pretender to the throne, so Han's 'royal status' is questionable. However, if Han indeed was the rightful King of Corellia, then his children surely would have been royalty.

Leia Organa Solo, as you noted, was the daughter of Padme Amidala, once a Queen of Naboo. As she was democratically elected to be Queen, it is unlikely that her children would automatically be royalty. Note that Padme's parents, Ruwee and Jobal Naberrie, do not appear to be especially prominent in *Star Wars Episode II*. However, after Padme's death, Leia was adopted by [Bail Organa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bail_Organa) and his wife, Queen [Breha Organa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Breha_Organa). As Bail Organa did not continue as head of state until his death, later becoming a Senator, it is unknown if his grandchildren would have any royal status. As Alderaan was destroyed by the Empire, however, any royal line there effectively ended.

The Solos had three children: Jacen, Jaina, and Anakin. Of the three, Anakin, who died as a teenager, is the only one without explicit royal connections *on his own*. Jaina Solo eventually married [Jagged Fel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jagged_Fel), who went on to become emperor of the revived empire, founding member of the Fel dynasty. As such, presumably Jaina had some form of royal title as his wife *([Fate of the Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fate_of_the_Jedi) series, various comics)*.

Finally, Jacen Solo was the lover of [Tenel Ka Djo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tenel_Ka_Djo), the Queen of Hapes and ultimately fathered a child, Allana Solo, who was adopted by Han & Leia. Had Jacen openely married Tenel Ka, he would have had a royal title, and had his parentage of Allana, the [Chume'da](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chume%27da) of the Hapan system, become known, he would have been an important figure in Hapan society, despite it having a matriarchal society *([Legacy of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Force) series)*.

In summary, it is not clear if Leia's clear royal heritage was passed onto her children, but they did have some royal connection regardless, whether through their own relationships, or through a possible parental royal link.

Comment: Excellent! You may want to note which EU books covered these (similar to you mention of "Courtship") for further awsomeness.

Comment: @DVK - thanks, done!

Answer (score 5):

Since Alderaan was destroyed, her "Princess" title remained as an honorary one.

However, other active titles she held include:

- Senator
- Minister of State
- Chief of State
- Jedi Knight

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Leia_Organa_Solo

Her children are never referred to as Alderaan royalty. They gained their fame primarily from their parents essentially being the founders of the New Republic. Leia's children all eventually held the title of Jedi Knight, and some held other titles later on.

Answer (score -2):

These are moot points as all of Leia's children joined the Jedi order and Jedi do not rule over others and would have to renounce any royal status, as would Leia herself as she joined the order as well.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Code

Comment: I don't think so - Leia never renounced her royal lineage, and she was a Jedi Knight. The Jedi Code was changed in the new Jedi Order

Answer (score -2):

In the British Royal family, the offspring of a princess and a commoner is also a commoner. The daughter of Princess Anne and Mark Phillips is Zara Phillips (no Princess, Lady or other honorific).

Comment: But the offspring of Prince Charles and Lady Diana (not a princess until she married a prince) are Princes. I think that you are forgetting to take into account all the intricacies of English royalty